# Gvim won't launch after installing using software center

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gvim

I'm using a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and have installed Gvim using 'Ubuntu Software'. Problem is- Trying to launch from the sidebar where the icon appears, nothing happens. Any clues?

Thanks,
Danny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gvim - I remember it well (I got out of the professional coding game a long time ago when the world decided to offshore ... but thats off topic).

Which of the following packages did you install?

- vim
- vim-gnome
- vim-tiny
- vim-athena
- vim-athena-py2
- vim-gnome-py2
- vim-gtk
- vim-gtk-py2
- vim-gtk3
- vim-gtk3-py2
- vim-nox
- vim-nox-py2

What happens if you try to launch gvim from a terminal?

Comment: I didn't install a package, but the app "gvim" from Ubuntu's app manager. If I try to run from terminal: I need to sudo and it works. Without sudo: "Could not create gnome accelerators directory `/home/danny/.gnome2/accels': Permission denied
E852: The child process failed to start the GUI". Thanks! can I make it run through the icon without going through the terminal?

Comment: Ubuntu's app manager will in effect have installed some of the aforementioned packages. Can you post the results of `ls -ld . .gnome2` and `groups`. Is the icon on 1) the desktop 2) the result of typing **gvim** into unity dash or 3) permanently locked to the launcher on the left hand side? I think there is some permissions problem - as a test I executed `chown root:root .gnome2` to replicate your problem by removing permissions to that folder - but gvim just launched as expected with no error.

Comment: :~$ groups
danny adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
:~$ ls -ld . .gnome2
drwxr-xr-x 32 Danny danny 4096 Jun 30 16:29 .
drwx------  3 root  root  4096 Jun 29 15:09 .gnome2

Comment: The icon is 3) locked to the launcher.

Comment: For some reason, your .gnome2 folder is owned by **root** with no permissions to **danny**. I suggest running `sudo chown -R Danny:danny .gnome2` to change the permissions of .gnome2 and all sub directories. Like I said, I changed my configuration to yours ... and it ran ok. Give that a go. Also, when complete, try running gvim from the dash as per #2 in my previous comment.

Comment: Chingching! that nails it. And it actually makes Vim much better looking and interact better with the Ubuntu style than previously running from cmd line. Thanks!

Comment: No worries - glad I could help someone after all the help I've been given. I'm not sure how this question gets marked as "answered" ... I suppose the moderators will let us know!